# Why is the size of this struct 24?

Tags: c++, c, struct, sizeof, memory-alignment

I have a structure of which I want to calculate its size:

```
#pragma pack(push,4)
struct  MyStruct
{  
    uint32_t i1;    /* size=4, offset=0. */
    uint32_t i2;    /* size =4 offset =4 */
    uint16_t s1;    /* size =2 offset=8 */
    unsigned char c[8]; /* size=8 offset=12*/
    uint16_t s2;    /* size=2 offset=20. */
    uint16_t s3;    /* size=2 offset=24. */

} ; // total size is 26 

static_assert(sizeof(MyStruct) == 24, "size of MyStruct incorrect");
#pragma pack(pop)
```

The static assert shows that the size is 24, but my calculation shows that it should be 26.

Why is the size 24?

I am working on windows 7, 32 bit application using visual studio 2012

Comment: Stating the platform / compiler would have been nice, because both `#pragma` is *by definition* compiler-dependent, and packing / alignment is *by definition* platform-dependent.

Comment: Have you tried adding the sizes together? 4 + 4 + 2 + 8 + 2 + 2 = 22, not 26.

Comment: Your offset calculations are wrong. Each new offset is the previous offset, plus the size of the previous variable, or else zero if there is no previous variable. So the offset of c is 8+2=10. You added 4 by mistake.

Comment: @kaz Look for padding and alignment. The actual size is 24 and not 22 as you calculated. I used wrong type of padding and alignment and get the size wrong at 26. see the answer below.

Comment: @mans I did not say anything about the size of the struct; I said that the size of the members adds up to 22.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The alignment of `uint16_t` is only 2, hence the offsets are:

```
#pragma pack(push,4)
struct  MyStruct
{  
    uint32_t i1;        /* offset=0  size=4 */
    uint32_t i2;        /* offset=4  size=4 */
    uint16_t s1;        /* offset=8  size=2 */
    unsigned char c[8]; /* offset=10 size=8 */
    uint16_t s2;        /* offset=18 size=2 */
    uint16_t s3;        /* offset=20 size=2 */
                        /* offset=22 padding=2 (needed to align MyStruct) */
} ; // total size is 24
```

**Edit**
The padding at the end is necessary to ensure that all elements of

```
MyStruct A[10]; // or
MyStruct*B = new MyStruct[10];
```

are aligned appropriately. This requires that `sizeof(MyStruct)` is a multiple of  `alignof(MyStruct)`. Here, `sizeof(MyStruct)`=6*`alignof(MyStruct)`.

Any `struct`/`class` type is always padded to the next multiple of its alignment.

Comment: But I set the pack to be 4, so I set the alignment to 4. also why s1 is different?

Comment: Might want to mention the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) of the MS-specific `#pragma pack`: "The alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a multiple of n or a multiple of the size of the member, whichever is **smaller**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: #pragma pack sets the maximum alignment, so members normally requiring more than 4 bytes alignment will be 4 byte aligned, members requiring less than 4 bytes get their usual alignment.

Comment: /* offset=22 padding=2 (needed to align MyStruct) */
why do we need padding at the end? assume that the next item is a char, then there is no need for this padding?

Answer (score 22):

In addition to Walter's answer, consider catching this fish yourself. All you need is the printf function and simple arithmetic:

```
  struct MyStruct ms;

  printf("sizeof(ms): %zd\n", sizeof(ms));

  printf("i1\t%td\n", (uint8_t*)&ms.i1 - (uint8_t*)&ms);
  printf("i2\t%td\n", (uint8_t*)&ms.i2 - (uint8_t*)&ms);
  printf("s1\t%td\n", (uint8_t*)&ms.s1 - (uint8_t*)&ms);
  printf("c \t%td\n", (uint8_t*)&ms.c  - (uint8_t*)&ms);
  printf("s2\t%td\n", (uint8_t*)&ms.s2 - (uint8_t*)&ms);
  printf("s3\t%td\n", (uint8_t*)&ms.s3 - (uint8_t*)&ms);
```

(`%zd` is for printing `size_t`, `%td` for printing `ptrdiff_t`. A plain `%d` will probably work just fine on most systems.)

Output:

```
sizeof(ms): 24
i1      0
i2      4
s1      8
c       10
s2      18
s3      20
```

Comment: +1 for using the correct format specifiers for `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t`, although `%d` most definitely won't work fine (because of the signedness mismatch). (and `ptrdiff_t` is likely to be an alias for `long`, especially on 64-bit systems, so again, it's not recommended to print it with `%d`.)

Comment: Why not use `char*` rather than `uint8_t*`?

Comment: @KeithThompson Out of old habit. I never use the char type for anything but strings. Because the default primitive data types in C are dangerous, non-portable and should be abandoned in favour of the stdint.h types. But also because it is a very bad idea to use char in any kind of arithmetics, particularly when doing bit or byte manipulations, because of char's impl. defined signedness.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, but sizes and offsets are defined in terms of bytes, not octets. If `CHAR_BIT > 8`, `uint8_t` doesn't exist. And of course all your uses of pointer subtraction could be replaced by the standard `offsetof` macros.

Comment: @KeithThompson offsetof is indeed more elegant, been too long since I used that one, I had forgotten it exists :) Anyway, the above code shows that there is no mysterious magic involved in struct padding: you can easily write code to find out where everything is stored at.

Comment: Why use `printf` in C++? Just use the C++ iostreams and you must not know all those weird `%zd` and `%td` stuff.

Comment: @Walter This was tagged both C and C++, I gave a C answer. But certainly you can do the very same thing in C++ using cout.

Comment: @Lundin A yes, I didn't notice the `C` tag. Is `uint16_t` etc also `C` standard?

Comment: @Walter Yes it is standard since C99.

Comment: Where is "end 24" printed?

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD I would guess it is copy/paste of some debug code. I'll delete it.

Answer (score -6):

4 4 2 8 2 2 - will be packed as:

4 4 4 8 2 2 - the last two are combined together in 4 bytes. the third item needs padding, the last and pre last do not.